# Get "html" tag with renderer2 to set style height

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to do this, but it's not working:

```
 constructor(public renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let body = document.body
    let html = document.getRootNode()
    this.renderer.setStyle(html, 'height', '100%')
    this.renderer.setStyle(html, 'background-color', 'blue')
    this.renderer.setStyle(body, 'height', '25%')
    this.renderer.setStyle(body, 'display', '-ms-flexbox')

  }
```

This component contains a unique structure, this is why I need to modify the root tag in this place.

Answer (score 0):

It´s so simple:

```
let html = document.documentElement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HostBinding also to bond styles to the elements, Import HostBinding from @angular/core and set style as below.

@HostBinding('style.height') bgHeight:string='100px';

@HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') bgColor:string = 'blue';